# What is the optimal way to update an index of an array that is in the state?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

Lets say i have an state and a variable `bananas`

```
state = {
    bananas: []
}
```

And that there is some data in that array, so this means the array isn't empty.

I want to update only one element of the array. I have and `index` variable with the index that I want to change.

My first try was this:

```
let newBananas = this.state.bananas
newBananas[index] = value
this.setState({bananas: newBananas })
```

but I don't think this is good.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs) question which helped me a little bit, but my case is different because I don't want to concat or add a new element to the array, I want to modify only one element at a given position.

What is the best way of doing this with good practices?

Comment: Why don't you think this is a good practice? I do the same thing at work, except I usually make a clone with a spread operator so that it's not mutating the original state variable.

Comment: Yeah, just create a copy of the array first: `let newBananas = [...this.state.bananas];` (or `Array.from(this.state.bananas)`).

Comment: One thing to note, is that modifying a state variable does *not* trigger a lifecycle update (I found this out the hard way), so I highly suggest creating a copy. Otherwise this is a good react practice because it's clean, and effective.

Comment: so a good practice would be create a new array with spread operator?

Comment: Good practice is to create a new array without modifying the existing array, the spread operator is one option.

Comment: Good practice is to not mutate existing state. That implies creating new objects/arrays when you want to change them. *How* to do that is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the best way of doing this would be

```
let newBananas = [...this.state.bananas]
newBananas[index] = value
this.setState({bananas: newBananas })
```

Thanks for all the comments!